# How to store json data in String varaiables?

Tags: java, android, json

How to store `json` data in `String` variables. I tried but it is showing an error.I want to store below `json` in one normal `string`.I tried lot it's always showing error.

```
[  
   {  
      "order":0,
      "name":"expenseType",
      "required":true,
      "type":"text",
      "placeholder":"Expense Type"
   },
   {  
      "order":1,
      "name":"date",
      "required":true,
      "type":"text",
      "placeholder":"Expense Date"
   },
   {  
      "order":3,
      "name":"amount",
      "required":true,
      "type":"number",
      "placeholder":"Enter Amount"
   },
   {  
      "order":4,
      "name":"description",
      "required":true,
      "type":"text",
      "placeholder":"Description"
   },
   {  
      "order":5,
      "name":"imageUrls",
      "type":"fileUpload",
      "options":[ urls:string]
   }
]
```

> Error:  org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 641

Comment: What is the error it is throwing?

Comment: @ Pradeep Simha it's showing compile error

Comment: share your java code

Comment: @YoLo just i want to store as string

Comment: You need to tell us what is the compile error you are getting and show us the relevant code :)

Comment: Share the error;

Comment: @ Imran Please check my undated code

Comment: your json is invalid

Comment: "options":[ urls:string] is not json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use toString() on JsonObject.

```
String jsonString=jsonObject.toString();
```

Rcreate Json Object from String .

```
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

If you want Json String as constant then just paste it beetween double quotes. Example json .

{
   "token":"",
   "type":"1",
   "message":{
      "type":1,
      "message":"message"
   } 
   }

And as String it is.

```
  String jsonString ="{\n" +
           "   \"token\":\"\",\n" +
           "   \"type\":\"1\",\n" +
           "   \"message\":{\n" +
           "      \"type\":1,\n" +
           "      \"message\":\"message\"\n" +
           "   }\n" +
           "}";
```

Comment: Same thing i tried sir...i getting error `Error: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 641`

Comment: Then your json is not valid i think . Check in online Json Viewer  if you are using valid json or not

Answer (score 0):

you can use GSON , create your object class

Gradle :

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Java :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String myJson = "my string json array";
List<Object> list= gson.fromJson(myJson,new TypeToken<List<Object>>(){}.getType());
```

See the [Documentation](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: i did use any asytask...just i want to store as a string bro

Comment: it is not an asytask , Gson is a library for Parse data, it make life very easy , Object -> Json or Json -> Object